# How to link Android application and web-service?

Tags: java, php, android

I made an Android application and I have a web-service (written in PHP). The service must send a message to application, so while my Android application works in the background and monitors web-service, it gets the message from service.

How can I organize this interaction? Thank you

Comment: Q: How does your test client invoke the web service?  Just have Android do the same thing.  You *do* have a working test client, don't you ;-)?

Comment: A quick search here will give you plenty of examples of others asking the same question.

Answer (score 0):

[C2DM](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/android/c2dm/) is probably the most efficient way to push notifications to your android phone (no extra polling needed). Give it a look.

If you want to do it with the background service, you can set the service to be woken up every x minutes with `AlarmManager` and send http request to your server to check for updates. However this does consume battery if you do it too often.

Comment: It's worth considering the devices you are aiming at. C2DM is only for API >=8 (android 2.2) so may not be an option. it will not work for devices running older api levels

Comment: Another note, C2DM is not for payload, it is only to notify your app that there are updates available from your web service, you will still need to use `HttpClient` or similar to connect to your service to obtain the payload.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples on the web with a quick google search or even on here.

A couple of samples:

http://blog.dahanne.net/2009/08/16/how-to-access-http-resources-from-android/
http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient
http://www.anddev.org/calling_a_web_service_from_android-t348.html

Remember that anything that could take time should be run in a thread outside of the UI thread

I'd suggest using a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
Please have a read of [this performance article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)